# How to find entity referred as a foreign key in Entity Framework dynamically

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, objectcontext

We have a `Country` class which is added as a reference in a few other entities:

```
public class Country 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

From above by using `Country` entity, how can we find that it is used in `Group` and `User` class? Any generic way so that we can utilize it for any entity type?

I got the code which gives used foreign key in entity

```
 public IEnumerable<string> GetFKPropertyNames<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        using (var context = new DataContext())
        {

            ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
            ObjectSet<TEntity> set = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();

            var Fks = set.EntitySet.ElementType.NavigationProperties.SelectMany(n => n.GetDependentProperties());
            return Fks.Select(fk => fk.Name);
        }
    }
```

var result = GetFKPropertyNames<**User**>();

result will return "**CountryId**" as it used as foreign key.

Now, what we need is. If we provide Country entity it should give us **User** and **Group** as these two entities have **CountryId** as a foreign key .

How can we achieve this?

Comment: It is not necessarily required to add Foreign Key. combination of virtual and key makes it as foreign key

Comment: What do you mean about a "dynamic" and "generic" way to find what is being referenced?

Comment: @krillgar - Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Able to identify the way, it can be achieve as -

```
 public IEnumerable<string> GetReferencedEntities<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        using (var context = new DataContext())
        {

            ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
            ObjectSet<TEntity> set = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();

            string tEntityName = typeof(TEntity).Name;

            var Fks = set.EntitySet.EntityContainer.AssociationSets.Where(r => r.Name.EndsWith(tEntityName)).ToList();

            //var Fks = set.EntitySet.ElementType.NavigationProperties.Select(n => n.DeclaringType);
            return Fks.Select(fk => fk.Name);
        }
    }
var result = GetReferencedEntities<Country>();
```

The result output will have **Group_Country** and **User_Country**. These are the ones in which country is being used as a foreign key.